# ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -121

Tags: android

Has any one get this "-121" error before?

I saw few post got the same error (but with error code -130) and seem solving the problem by removing some weird strings. However, I don't find anything like this in my code and the error message looks meaningless to me:

```
String index out of range: -121
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -121
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutor.java:416)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.run(GradleTasksExecutor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

Comment: Add the code that is causing this exception. The error message tells you that you are doing something very wrong with an index.

Comment: Hey, there is no special of the code...I just add a activity. I can run the code in my device, but it gives me the error when I wanna export the apk? What do you mean by "very wrong with an index"? How can I find the code making it very wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Wanna update that @greenapps is right. I solve this issue by removing some new added xml